# Bootstrap Tooltips have disabled parts of my javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So here is a issue I am experiencing that is driving me nuts. As soon as I enable Bootstrap tooltips on my  tags, the custom JavaScript I have won't trigger. If I remove the Bootstrap code that triggers the tooltip from the tag, everything works. [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ctrghh7g/1/)

Working Example (remove: **data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Parent Title Text."** and it will work):

```
<li>
    <a class="toggle-data-options" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Parent Title Text.">Parent 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline;"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" style="display:none;"></span>
    </a>    
        <div class="data-options" style="display: none">
            <a class="less-data-options" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Child Item 1 Text">Child Item 1</a>    
            <a class="less-data-options" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Child Item 2 Text">Child Item 2</a>
            <a class="less-data-options" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Child Item 3 Text">Child Item 3</a>    
        </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enable the bootstrap tooltip it inserts the tooltip `<div>` immediately after `.toggle-data-options`.

`.data-options` is no longer the `.next()` element, so there is no match. Use `.nextAll()` instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.toggle-data-options').on('click', function () {
        $(this).nextAll('.data-options').toggle('fast');
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).find('span').slideToggle(0);
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ctrghh7g/2/)

Comment: Thanks, didn't even know .nextAll existed. You learn something new every day.